# app:mergeDebugResources FAILED duplicate resources error in android when i put the min sdk version to 19

Tags: android, kotlin, duplicates, resources, android-min-sdk

when the min sdk was 21 the application run fine now when i minimized it to 19 the error duplicate resources  (app:mergeDebugResources FAILED) appears for all drawable files
here is some of the gradle file

```
    android {
    defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 28
    minSdkVersion 19
   }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

      }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0      
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" 
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'   
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

version of gradle you need to change

Comment: does this affects the application for newer versions of android ?

Comment: and when i changed the gradle the error jcenter.bintray.com:443 failed to respond  appears

Comment: No it will not affects the application for newer versions of android